# How do I use Google-OpenId after April 20th with omniauth-openid?

Tags: ruby, omniauth, google-openid

I'm currently using [omniauth-openid](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth-openid) in my app in order to enable a login with my google account.

More or less everything I had to do was to create the method

```
use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :open_id,  :name => 'openid',
    :identifier => 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id',
    :store => OpenID::Store::Filesystem.new('/tmp')
end
```

and the magic started and worked right out of the box.

Now, I receive the warning

> Important: Google has deprecated OpenID 2.0 and will shut it down after a migration period. If your app uses OpenID 2.0, you must migrate your app by the shutdown date April 20, 2015, as shown in the migration timetable.

Unfortunately, I got no clue what to do in order to be able to log in to my app after April 20th.

Are there any resources that could help me here?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID2 What are wrong with the hyperlinks in *If your app uses OpenID 2.0, the userinfo endpoint, or OAuth 2.0 login (early version) ... for information about switching from OpenID 2.0 to Google+ Sign-In, see Switch to Google+ Sign-In. If your app is on a platform that Google+ Sign-In does not support, or if you want to work directly with the OAuth 2.0 REST APIs, you can base your code directly on OpenID Connect (OAuth 2.0 for Login). For step-by-step instructions on switching to OpenID Connect, see OpenID 2.0 (Migration).*

Answer (score 0):

Your application is going to be one of thousands that will suddenly stop working on April 20.

You should set up your application to use [the Google OAuth gem](https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2).  If you set the **openid_realm** option in the gem, it will give you the user's old OpenID URL so that you can look them up in your database.  Note that Google is only guaranteeing the OpenID URL in OAuth requests until 2017, so you should transition your users over to a new schema as soon as they log in with OAuth for the first time.